# Where is the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework.dll in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Where is the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework.dll in Visual Studio 2013? I'm using NUnit on an API and I cannot add that library in a new machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its only available in the ultimate edition of Visual Studio 2013...

Comment: That's not right -- our SDET has it on his premium edition version -- he's got the same version as me though, and I don't seem to have it. -- It's got to be some SDK or something.