# Where to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I am missing a reference to this .dll file and I can't find it from the add references tab, it is not there in both extensions and frameworks and neither nuget package manager lists it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623765/where-is-the-microsoft-visualstudio-qualitytools-webtestframework-dll-in-visual](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623765/where-is-the-microsoft-visualstudio-qualitytools-webtestframework-dll-in-visual)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in Add Reference tab but you have to target .Net 4.5. I can access it from VS2012 Express Edition, VS2013 Express Edition, and VS2013 Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Even when targeting .NET 4.5 I still only see `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` assemblies in the reference manager, no `WebTestFramework` assembly.

Turns out it's in a NuGet package now. Open the NuGet package manager and search for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework`, and you're done. Doesn't matter what version of the .NET Framework you're targeting either - I'm targeting 4.7.2 and it still works fine.